# Postgres command to remove backslashes works in console, but not with ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, pg

This Postgres command removes all backslashes when run from the `psql` command line:

```
UPDATE table SET column = REGEXP_REPLACE(column, '\B', '', 'g');
```

This Rails command doesn't work (it runs without error, but doesn't remove the backslash):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE table SET column = REGEXP_REPLACE(column, '\B', '', 'g'))
```

It looks like Rails changes the query and runs this (I inspected the output from running the query in the console):

```
UPDATE table SET column = REGEXP_REPLACE(column, 'B', '', 'g')
```

The Postgres command also successfully removes the backslash when run from the `psql` command line:

```
UPDATE table SET column = REGEXP_REPLACE(column, '\\', '', 'g')
```

This same Postgres command surprisingly errors out when run with Rails:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE table SET column = REGEXP_REPLACE(column, '\\', '', 'g')")
```

Here's the error:

> PG::InvalidRegularExpression: ERROR:  invalid regular expression:
>   invalid escape \ sequence

Here's the Postgres version that's set in my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
```

Can you please explain why I'm getting this error and how to write Rails code that will remove all backslashes from a column?  This will be run on a large data set and I'll need a fast solution.

Comment: Well why not \\B ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is complicated by having multiple things that want to interpret `\` in their own way:

1. `\` means something inside a double quoted string in Ruby. So `"\B"` is just a misleading and complicated way of writing `"B"` in Ruby. You'd need to say `"\\B"` to get a string containing the two characters `\B`.
2. `\` means something inside a PostgreSQL regex. Hence the presence of `\B` in PostgreSQL's regexes so that you don't have to count `\`s when looking at things like `\\\\` inside another language, you'd just have slightly less ugly things like `\\B`.

To get around your problem you could just properly escape your escapes:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE table SET column = REGEXP_REPLACE(column, '\\B', '', 'g')")
```

When the database sees that, it will see:

```
UPDATE table SET column = REGEXP_REPLACE(column, '\B', '', 'g')
```

because `\\` means "give me just one `\`" in a double quoted Ruby string.

I'd probably simplify further and use the [SQL `replace` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER):

> `replace(string text, from text, to text)`
>   Replace all occurrences in *string* of substring *from* with substring *to*.

combined with a `%q{...}` string in Ruby:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(%q{
  update table
  set column = replace(column, '\', '')
})
```

The `%q{...}` gets rid of one escaping problem because it acts like a single-quoted string in Ruby so `\` doesn't mean anything special. Using `replace` in the SQL gets rid of another escaping problem because it only works with plain old strings (rather than regexes represented by strings) so `\` again doesn't mean anything.